# mergeclass overriding with props attribute

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-hooks, griffel.js

I have color attribute in props but it can be left undefined, in case it is undefined the rendered color should come from hooks defined by makestyle provided by griffel otherwise props should override color of stroke `

```
 const a = { stroke: props.data!.lineChartData![0].color! };
    console.log(a);
    return (
      <>
        <path
          // className={myClass.line}

          className={mergeClasses(myClass.line, a)}
          // style={{ stroke: props.data!.lineChartData![0].color! }}
          d={line.current(_points)}
        />

style file where myclass is defined 
export const useClasses = makeStyles({
  line: {
    stroke: tokens.colorPaletteRedForeground2,
    fill: 'transparent',
    opacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: '2px',
  },

in base file myclass=useclass(); //provided by griffel library
```

i have tried inline style approach but i want to go with merge style approach.

Comment: `props.data!.lineChartData![0].color!` seems to be invalid syntax. Did you mean `props.data?.lineChartData?[0].color` ?